# Is my sqlite query wrong?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am trying to create a database table for Android.
MY error message is the following.

```
08-02 10:16:50.075: E/AndroidRuntime(29093): Caused by:  
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "index": syntax error (code 1): , while  
compiling: CREATE TABLE featured_kluster (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,   index  
TEXT, term TEXT)
```

What is wrong with my sql query?

```
    public interface TableKluster extends BaseColumns {

        public String table = "featured_kluster";

        public String index = "index";
        public String term = "term";

        public String CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + table + " ("
                + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + index + " TEXT, "
                + term + " TEXT)";
    }
```

I don't know what is wrong with the index field..

Answer (score 11):

Index is an SQL keyword; replace it and it should work.

Comment: or escape it `CREATE TABLE foo ("index" TEXT)` - would not recommend though

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an unquoted reserved keyword as an identifier.  Ideally do what ClaireG suggests (use a non-keyword identifier), if that's not an option you can use one of the [keyword escape mechanisms offered by SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

MS style using []

```
CREATE TABLE [table] (
```

MySQL style using backticks/grave accents

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
```

ANSI style using double quotes

```
CREATE TABLE "table" (
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue on my Android app. You cannot use "index" as column name, it's not allowed, you have to change it to something else, like "klusterIndex".